# Using the Total Contribution Qualifying Date filter

Tags: contributions

I am using the total contributions column and setting the total contribution qualifying date filter to previous fiscal year. However, the total contributions seem to be showing contributions for all time. The filter does not appear to be working. Any ideas? Thank You!

Comment: Welcome!  I think a little bit more information is necessary to answer your question.  What screen are you looking at?  Is this a report, or a search?  If you're not sure, editing your question to include a URL will help.  Feel free to change your organization's name to "example.org" in the URL.  Also - "qualifying date" isn't a field that comes with CiviCRM, so is probably added custom.  Editing your question to include a screenshot may be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. This is a report.

Comment: Hi Megan - I think we need to know which report.  Can you please include a screenshot?